# How to share a variable among threads in joblib using external module

Tags: scikit-learn, joblib

I am trying to modify sklearn source code. In particular, I am modifying GridSearch source code, in a way that the separate processes/threads that evaluate the different model configuration share a variable among themselves. I need each thread/process to read/update that variable during running time in order to modify their execution according to what the other threads obtained. More specifically the parameter that I would like to share is **best**, in the snippet below:

```
out = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_score)(clone(base_estimator), X, y, best, self.early,train=train, test=test,parameters=parameters,**fit_and_score_kwargs) for parameters, (train, test) in product(candidate_params, cv.split(X, y, groups)))
```

Nota bene that the *_fit_and_score* function is in a separate module.
Sklearn utilizes joblib for parallelization, but I am not able to understand how I can effectively do that using an external module. In joblib doc this code is provided:

```
>>> shared_set = set()
>>> def collect(x):
...    shared_set.add(x)
...
>>> Parallel(n_jobs=2, require='sharedmem')(
...     delayed(collect)(i) for i in range(5))
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> sorted(shared_set)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

but I am not able to understand how to make it run in my context. You can find the source code here:

- gridsearch: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dbac82d362f296dc2746f10e43ffa1615660/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L704
- fit_and_score: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dbac82d362f296dc2746f10e43ffa1615660/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L406

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with python's Manager (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager), simple code for example:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()
q = manager.Namespace()
q.flag = False

def test(i, q):
    #update shared var in 0 process
    if i == 0:
        q.flag = True

    # do nothing for few seconds
    for n in range(100000000):
        if q.flag == True:
            return f'process {i} was updated'

    return 'process {i} was not updated'

out = Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(test)(i, q) for i in range(4))
```

out:

```
['process 0 was updated',
 'process 1 was updated',
 'process 2 was updated',
 'process 3 was updated']
```